# DataTableColumns resizable only on Maximize

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a **p:dataTable** with plenty of data in it. I want the user to be able to resize the columns, but only if the window is maximized; if the window is not maximized the columns are overlapped and reading the data is impossible.

However, that only happens if the poperty **resizableColumns** from **p:dataTable** is **true**; if it's **false** and the window isn't maximized a scrollbar appears.

This is exactly what I want, if the window is maximized **resizableColumns=true** else **resizableColumns=false** and a scrollbar(scrollbar won't appear if resizableColumns=true, no matter if maximzed or not).

Here some pictures:

[image: This is how it looks like if the window is maximized => columns should be resizable]

[image: Columns overlapped]

Is it possible to check if windows is maximized and set the resizableColumns value afterwards?

Comment: I don't think you can solve this problem without using pure CSS. [Media queries](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#media-queries) can be a solution for you. Just override PF default styles to use different sizes depending which resolution you're displaying. Keep in mind that technique [is not valid in some browsers like IE 8 and some mobile ones](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries).

Comment: Yes, it was only with CSS possible. I set the size for the columns to a fix width. If the browser was maximized the columns width were set automatically so it fits the whole page (kinda weird, even  tho the size was set for each to 200px). However, if i resized the browser, he set the width to 200px and the columns didn't overlapp, which was exactly what I needed.